# Getting 'Error: socket hang up' when passing json from microservice over backend to frontend

Tags: python, node.js, angular

I'm working in a team project where we basically have three architecture parts.

1. Angular Frontend
2. Node.js backend
3. Microservices in different programming languages

I'm trying to integrate my microservice (Python/Flask implementation) in the architecture with everything running on localhost. Basically I just want to hand on a json from 3. over 2. to 1.

These are the relevant Code-Snippets:

Microservice (Solver.py takes about 10 secs to solve and give json):

```
@app.route('/give-solution')
def give_solution():
    importlib.reload(Solver)  
    return(Solver.jsonSolution)
```

Backend:

```
app.get('/pass-solution', (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get("127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution")
        .then((resultn) => {       
          console.log(resultn);
          return res.status(201).json(resultn.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });   
});
```

Frontend (.component.ts file of subpage)

```
this.http.get("127.0.0.1:3000/pass-solution")
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.outputString = JSON.stringify(data);
      this.outputJson = JSON.parse(this.outputString);
      this.outputTable = new MatTableDataSource(this.outputJson);
      });
```

When I try to access the json solution in frontend I get the following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:453:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2',
      host: '127.0.0.1:5000'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      protocol: 'http:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '3128',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution'
    },
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      connection: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.19.2\r\n' +
        'host: 127.0.0.1:5000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      _redirectable: [Circular],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3128/http://127.0.0.1:5000/give-solution',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function]
}
```

I can avoid the error by either passing the json directly from microservice to frontend or leaving out `importlib.reload(Solver)`. So I guess it's just the waiting time for json response that the architecture can't handle. I've already tried to extend `timeout`, but this didn't help. I'm happy for suggestions!

Comment: How much time does it take for the Python server to resolve? Also, what are the logs of Node.js backend?

Comment: The python server needs about 10 secs for the answer. What logs do you mean and how do I get them? The error log from above is from Node.js

Comment: @tbking I get this when I start the backend. It just says, that all database connections are successful.
node ./backend/server.js
(node:16684) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover
and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:16684) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
Connected to database!
MySQL connected!

Comment: Seems like  the Python server is closing the connection abruptly before replying. Any error logs there? Or it could be a timeout issue. Does the error happen after a certain delay everytime?

Comment: @tbking There's no error logs and I don't think Python is the problem, as passing the json directly from Python server to frontend is working. Is there another way of forwarding the json in Node.js? Maybe without axios?